# How to change English statement to First Order Logic

Tags: if-statement, logic, artificial-intelligence, predicate, first-order-logic

I have an if/else statement that need to be changed to First Order Logic..

To reduce the number of applications that are used during online classes.

The If/else statement is below this:

```
For any Students,and any Lecturers 
If Students_Open_Other_Applications = true OR Students_in_Class_Session = false
 OR Lecturers_in_Class_Session = false AND Class_Mode = "F2F" AND Same_Session = true
    THEN Notice_Lecturer = true AND Notice_Students = true
```

I am actually not quite understand and try build the FOL like this (I dont know is it correct or not)..

```
∀x ,∀y Students(x),Lecturers(y) [([OpenOtherApp(x) ∨ ¬InClass(x) ∨ ¬InClass(y)] ∧ ClassMode("F2F") ∧ SameSession(x,y)) 
→   Notice(x) ∧ Notice(y)]
```

Then, I try to separate it from two perspective:

Students :-

For every students, that open other app or not in class and class mode F2F
then lecturer and student in same class will be noticed

```
∀xStudents(x) [([OpenOtherApp(x)∨¬InClass(x)] ∧ ClassMode("F2F")) → (Notice(x) ∧ Notice(y))]
```

Lecturers:-

For every lecturer that not in class and class mode F2F
then lecturer and student in same class will be noticed

```
∀yLecturers(y) [(¬InClass(y) ∧ ClassMode("F2F")) → (Notice(x) ∧ Notice(y))]
```

I dont know if those three first order logics are true..
I need to combine both statement into one statement..
Can someone guide me through and thorough way?

Comment: How does this relate to Python?

Comment: I am sorry for the inconvenience. Since I got the task in Python, I thought Python tag would be reasonable to put.. may be not so..

Comment: It is no problem, I was just curious and thought I might have missed something?  I certainly can't be certain, but I think you will have little success it getting a response on this forum.  There maybe a more appropriate StackOverflow forum where you could ask this question such as [first-order-logic]

Comment: oh right.. thanks.. I'll edit the question then..